# Connecting a computer fan controller for multiple 12V DC fans to 120V AC

Tags: fan

I would be interested to control multiple fans in an application that is outside a computer. I didn't find any interesting product for controlling multiple 12V 120mm fans that I could connect to 120V with an adapter.

So my question is: if I'm going to use a computer fan controller, how could I connect it to 120V AC (assuming that I would be using a computer fan controller with thermal sensors, that could control more than 3 fans)?

If this is a bad idea, what should I use instead of a computer fan controller for multiple 12V 120mm fans?

Comment: Do you need to control the fan speed, or can you just buy fans that are the right speed? They make fans in the same shape as computer fans but take 120 VAC.

Comment: @longneck The fans are going to be thermally controlled. I was going to buy fans that have a low noise level, running at a specific speed. Also, the fans that you are talking about, can multiple of them be connected to a device that can control them as a function of temperature? Wouldn't these fans cost more? I want a low cost solution (computer fan controller that I found are around $40 and fans are between $10-20).

Answer (score 1):

Your plan of using a computer fan speed controller is acceptable. You should be able to power the fan controller with any regulated 12 volt power supply of sufficient capacity. Just make sure your controller does not also require 5 volts.

Comment: The computer fan controllers use molex plug for power. I don't know if they require the 5V as well. In all cases, I've never seen a 12V power supply with a molex plug. Do they even exist?

Comment: That's what wire cutters are for!

Comment: I'm not an expert with wire cutters, hence why I'm asking for possible options.

Comment: @m_power It should be fairly simple to cut the plug off, strip the wires if necessary, and connect them onto some other connector or directly to the power supply.